# During an iTunes sync, are MacBooks prevented from going into sleep mode?

Tags: iphone, itunes, data-synchronization, macbook-pro, power-management

I want to know this as I sometimes leave my iPhone unattended while syncing and I want to make sure that there's no cut off to the iPhone sync.

Answer (score 2):

Your MacBook *shouldn't* go to sleep **while iPhone sync is in progress.**  iTunes' sync needs to copy files from your Mac to the iOS device, and vice-versa. In either case, your Mac is accessing the hard drive.

Refer to [Mac OS X: Why your Mac might not sleep or stay in sleep mode – Apple Support](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1776). This section roughly halfway down the page is relevant:

> **Open applications can affect sleep**
>
> Software that accesses the hard drive will delay sleep mode until it
>   is either quit or done accessing the drive.  For example:
>
> - Songs playing in iTunes.
> - A movie disc playing in DVD Player.
>
> *[... lots more detail in the article ...]*

In your case, songs aren't playing in iTunes, but iTunes does keep accessing the drive as long as the sync is in progress, which should keep your MacBook awake.